# Is there a generic way of dealing with varying connection strings in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string

I have an application that needs to connect to a SQL database, and execute a SQL Agent Job.

The connection string I am trying to access is stored in the registry, which is easily enough pulled out.

This appliction is to be run on multiple computers, and I cannot guarantee the format of this connection string being consistent across these computers. Two that I have pulled out for example are:

```
Data Source=Server1;Initial Catalog=DB1;Integrated Security=SSPI;
Data Source=Server2;Initial Catalog=DB1;Provider=SQLNCLI.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;
```

I can use an object of type `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` to connect to the database with the first connection string, howevever, I get the following error when I pass the second to it:

> keyword not supported: 'provider'

Similarly, I can use the an object of type `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection` to connect to the database with the second connection string, howevever, I get the following error when I pass the first to it:

> An OLEDB Provider was not specified in the ConnectionString'

I can solve this by scanning the string for 'Provider' and doing the connect conditionally, however I can't help but feel that there is a better way of doing this, and handle the connection strings in a more generic fashion.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal way of handling this is storing the ADO.NET provider unique name (separately from the connection string) and using a [DB Provider Factory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wda6c36e.aspx).

Comment: Maybe I'm not quite understanding you. I have no control over what is stored. The connection strings are fixed, and I cannot store anything more.

Comment: Ah; well, then, you'll have to guess the provider from the connection string, unfortunately. There's no way to do this automatically.

Comment: For general info. Accepted answer was on above comment, I.e. this was not possible. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Use a [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx), initialize it with the connection string you find in registry and then read its ConnectionString property, which would normalize the connection string to proper SQL Client syntax.

Comment: The SqlConnectionStringBuilder won't work with his OleDbConnection object.

Comment: This still gives the same error: keyword not supported: 'provider'